# How do I organize DOM HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I want to organize my DOM HTML elements so that they appear like this:

> ```
> ADD AUTHOR (Button) // adds a whole new author
> (textbox for field) //New Author
> ADD BOOK (Button)   // adds new textfields under this author
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)
> //I want to be able to add more books here with DOM if it's from the same author
>
> (textbox for field) //New Author
> ADD BOOK (Button)   // adds new textfields under this author
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)
> //I want to be able to add more books here with DOM if it's from the same author
> ```

But what it does is:

> ```
> ADD AUTHOR (Button)
> (textbox for field)
> ADD BOOK (Button)
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)//this can be a new author or a authors' book
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field)
> (textbox for field) // there is no structure
> ```

I am trying to send this code by post to another .php so that I can insert into my database. Does this mean that the post will be a array of an array. So will I  read it as post['myBooksText['0']']?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<form action="insertIntoDB.php" method="post">
 <div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <button class="add_field_button">Add Author</button>
     <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"></div>
     <button class="add_sub_field_button">Add Author Books</button>
     <div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"></div>
 </div>
</form>
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton      = $(".add_sub_field_button"); //Add sub button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(add_subButton).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

</SCRIPT>
```